# Is this Steppenwolf with mother boxes in Dawn of Justice?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

I found this picture online in [here](https://geeks.media/stones-and-boxes-this-is-how-mother-boxes-in-the-dceu-differ-from-marvel-s-infinity-stones).

I want to confirm the authenticity that these are real mother boxes and if so how come Steppenwolf is already in possession with them.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes these are the mother boxes. Though this is not the real Steppenwolf or the real mother boxes.  This is just a [premonition](https://youtu.be/TD0JW6VxXBI) scene of whats to come that Lex witnesses. It sets up that Steppenwolf, or some creature atleast is looking for the Mother Boxes.

Comment: Please read complete question & try answering in length. Are these the three motherboxes?

Comment: Did you watch the movie and do you understand the word premonition? Because im not sure how to answer more directly other than explaining what premonition means.

Comment: Thank you for expanding the answer. Don't get offended but your first answer wasn't complete. Now that you edited your answer I got what I'm looking for.